# Generic use of a class nested in a generic

Tags: java, generics, inner-classes

Even if it's not a good practise, I want to know for the sake of knowing why.

The below code doesn't compile, and I don't really get why.

---

Let's say I have an abstract definition of a Joker, a Queen, and a King :

```
abstract class JokerA {
    //JokerA does things
}

abstract class QueenA<J extends JokerA> {
    //QueenA makes use of J
    class Princess {
        void receiveGift(Gift gift) {
            /* ... */
        }
    }
}

abstract class KingA<Q extends QueenA<?>> {
    KingA(Q.Princess princess) {
        Gift giftForPrincess = new Gift();
        princess.receiveGift(giftForPrincess);
    }
}
```

This works just fine.
However, I also want to define a more specialised, but still abstract, Joker, Queen and King

```
abstract class JokerB extends JokerA {
    //JokerB does some things differently
}

abstract class QueenB<J extends JokerB> extends QueenA<J> {
    //QueenB makes use of J sometimes differently, because she knows how JokerBs behave
}

abstract class KingB<Q extends QueenB<?>> extends KingA<Q> {
    KingB(Q.Princess princess) {
        super(princess); //error
    }
}
```

The error is :

> ```
> KingA(QueenA<capture<?>>.Princess) in KingA cannot be applied to (Q.Princess)
> ```

However, I can't see how the Princess class would be a different one.

Can anyone enlighten me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there is only one class here named `Princess`, which is `QueenA.Princess`. There is no `QueenB.Princess` -- if you write `QueenB.Princess` the compiler simply understands it to mean `QueenA.Princess`. Note that since `Princess` is a non-static inner class of `QueenA`, a generic class, `QueenA.Princess` is also a generic class (parameterized by the parameters of `QueenA`). When it's parameterized it looks like `QueenA<something>.Princess`.

Since the issue is a compatibility between two values of the class `Princess`, and which we noted above there is one such class, the only compatibility issue is about the generic type argument. The type that is passed in to `super()` is supposedly `Q.Princess`. But as we noted above, `Princess` belongs to `QueenA`, and not `QueenB` or `Q`. So the compiler at compile-time automatically re-writes this to `QueenA<something>.Princess`. The question is what is `something`. Basically, the question is `Q` is a `QueenA<what>`. `Q` is a type variable with the bound `QueenB<?>`. That means someone can use this class with `Q` being a `QueenB<X>` with `X` being any type that satisfies `QueenB`'s type parameter's bounds (namely a type that extends `JokerB`). So we cannot assume anything about `X` except that it is a subtype of `JokerB`. `QueenB<X>` extends `QueenA<X>`, so that means `Q` is a `QueenA<X>`. `<capture ...>` is just something the compiler prints to denote an unknown type. So at this point, the compiler has figured out that `Q.Princess` really means `QueenA<some unknown type that extends JokerB>.Princess`.

Then you pass it to `super()`, the constructor of `KingA`. The parameter type for this type parameter is also written `Q.Princess` (note: this is `KingA`'s `Q`, a different type parameter; don't get confused). If you follow the same analysis as above, you will see that the compiler sees that this `Q.Princess` really means `QueenA<some unknown type that extends JokerA>.Princess`.

The question is, is `QueenA<first unknown subtype>.Princess` a subtype of `QueenA<second unknown subtype>.Princess`? i.e. is `first unknown subtype` the same as `second unknown subtype`? (Remember generics are invariant.) The compiler from just looking at this will say it doesn't know whether they are the same or not, because two unknown types certainly could be different, so they are not compatible.

You might say, wait a minute, you know that `Q` is a `QueenA<X>` for some unknown type `X`, `KingB<Q>` is declared to extend `KingA<Q>`, so the `Q` in `KingB`'s scope for a particular object is the same as the `Q` in `KingB`'s scope. So the `Q`s are the same, and the unknown `X` is the same in both cases. But that doesn't apply here because `Q` is not being considered anymore. Remember that there is no type `Q.Princess`. The real type it means is `QueenA<something>.Princess`. That `QueenA<something>.Princess` is figured out at compile time when compiling each constructor for each class. Once it's figured out to be `unknown type`, it is then fixed as `unknown type`, and is not related to the `Q` that is the class's type parameter. So the two unknown types have no relation.

You can solve it by using a new type parameter instead of letting the compiler infer an unknown type. The type parameter can then allow you to connect separate uses of the type, to let the compiler know they are the same type. Something like this:

```
abstract class KingA<J extends JokerA, Q extends QueenA<J>> {
    KingA(Q.Princess princess) {
        Gift giftForPrincess = new Gift();
        princess.receiveGift(giftForPrincess);
    }
}

abstract class KingB<J extends JokerB, Q extends QueenB<J>> extends KingA<J, Q> {
    KingB(Q.Princess princess) {
        super(princess);
    }
}
```